# add .idea/libraries to .gitignore with Android Studio (and Gradle) a good idea?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, libraries, gitignore

With the change to the Gradle build system, I've noticed a bunch of *.xml files added to the .idea/libraries project directory. I'd assume this is how Android Studio/IntelliJ links libraries to the project.

Is it ok/recommended to add .idea/libraries to .gitignore? Since gradle handles all dependencies, I'd think either way these would be added/overwritten. Hoping for some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not.
I've been ignoring the whole .idea directory in my .gitignore, to avoid unnecessary changes get into the repo. Those IDE configurations can be regenerated from Gradle files.

Comment: I've been doing this for a bit now, and I think it should be noted that there are some perils to doing this. I've had a few instances where I didn't realize I changed some project specific setting (.idea folder) which caused problems with development (couldn't find libraries, modules, etc.). I'm not saying that you shouldn't follow this, but be aware that since you're not tracking the folder, you won't be made aware of changes made to that directory.